# Set div to widget's content only | Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm creating a custom sidebar on Wordpress to display independent blocks, and each block has a widget in it. To do so, I registered widget areas in functions.php, and then added those widget areas to my sidebar.

The sidebar is set like this :

```
<aside class="sidebar-right" role="complementary">
<div class="sidebar-widget">
    <?php if(!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('widget-area-1')) ?>
</div>
<div class="sidebar-widget">
    <?php if(!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('widget-area-2')) ?>
</div>
<div class="sidebar-widget">
    <?php if(!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('widget-area-3')) ?>
</div>
<div class="sidebar-widget">
    <?php if(!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('widget-area-4')) ?>
</div>
</aside>
```

I roughly want my sidebar to look like this : https://jsfiddle.net/b7xtksts/

This is how the widget is called in functions.php :

```
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => __('Widget Area 1'),
    'description' => __('Description'),
    'id' => 'widget-area-1',
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="%2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<div class="widget-title-background"><h3>',
    'after_title' => '</h3></div>'
));
```

Everything works fine, but I would like to add padding to every widget's content, without having to edit the original widget, so that every widget added in the future will fit properly thanks to the `padding`.

But if I set `padding` to, let's say, `<div id="%1$s" class="%2$s" style="padding:10px;">`, the padding is added to the whole widget, and the background title as well (which doesn't fill 100% of the box anymore).
I'm trying to figure out how I could set a padding to the widget's content without affecting the `div` title above. Since there are only before/after _widget and _title, how can I set a class to the content only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like we cannot add any specific class to content body of the widget.

One option I suggest is following:

1. Add padding to your parent widget div like you did e.g.

   .sidebar-widget{
         padding: 0 10px; 
   }
2. To remove the effect of 10px padding on sides on the title background div, we cancel it with the negative margin on side i.e.

   .widget-title-background{
            margin-left: -10px;
            margin-right: -10px;
       }

This will make your title's dark shaded div go around the corners, canceling the effect of the padding on the main div.

Comment: Great ! I tried this trick but with padding instead of margin to cancel it.. thank you.